# how to auto-skip the repeated raw in executemany?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I set a primary key for my table. Now I want to auto-skip the repeated raw when I executemany Insert.
What should I do? Here's my code and comment. Thank you guys.

```
cmd = \
'''
CREATE TABLE test(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
value INTEGER
)
'''
c.execute(cmd)
# now we have key = 1,2,3,4
c.executemany("INSERT INTO test VALUES (%s,%s)", [(1,100),
                                                  (3,100),
                                                  (2,100),
                                                  (4,100),])
# I want script automatically skip repeated row (1,200)
# if I add a try, except here, only the (5, 100) has been inserted
# because script jump out when exception raised
c.executemany("INSERT INTO testVALUES (%s, %s)", [(5,100),
                                                  (1,200),
                                                   (6,100)])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use that type of `INSERT` syntax, I would recommend that insetead of`executemany`, you use `execute` inside of a loop, and `commit` after each one (since if you don't `commit`, you'll lose the previously inserted items after the exception occurs).

Something like (where `conn` is your connection object):

```
for item_tuple in [(1,100), (3,100), (2,100), (4,100)]:
    try:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES (%s,%s)", item_tuple[0],
                   item_tuple[1])
        conn.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print "failed to insert: {0}".format(e)
        conn.rollback()
        # continue on to next item
```

This way, you can continue, swallow (and print) the exception if encountered (if desired, you could use a *regex* to search the exception text for a more narrow string so you don't swallow every exception, as doing that could be undesirable in some cases), and then `rollback` so you can continue using the connection (otherwise you'll get an error about trying to use a connection with an aborted transaction).

Another option, which wouldn't necessarily require you to `commit` on each item:

You could use the form of `INSERT` which takes `SELECT` statement as input, and you could structure it such that it selects the desired values, but checks to see if they're already present first, so if it is, the result of the select with be the empty set, and nothing will be inserted. (This would potentially have issues in a situation with multiple connections and transactions due to *MVCC*, but if you're the only one inserting into the table for the purposes of this check, it should be fine).

So, something like this:

```
for item_tuple in [(1,100), (3,100), (2,100), (4,100)]:
    c.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES (%s,%s)
                SELECT %s, %s
                WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                  FROM test
                                  WHERE value = %s
                                 )",
               item_tuple[0], item_tuple[1], item_tuple[0],
               item_tuple[1], item_tuple[1])
```